SSIS package creating a UTF-8 Flat file, need it to produce a ASCII flat file
I have an SSIS package that is producing a flat file.  The flat file is currently creating as a UTF-8 file, however I have just found out the flat file output needs to be ASCII.  Is there a setting I can change for the flat file destination connection manager?
The flat file connection manager on the general page has the code page set to 1252 (ANSI - Latin 1).  Under properties, unicode is set to false. Under the source advanced settings editor under Component Properties/Custom Properties alwaysUseDefaultCodePage is set to true and DefaultCodePage is set to 1252.
How do I get this flat file to output as ASCII?  What am I missing.  Any help is appreciated.
